# How to generate xsd file using java code?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

```
<complexType name="spThread">
        <sequence>
            <element name="SPThreadID" type="int" />
            <element name="durtime" minOccurs="0" default="0">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="int">
                        <minInclusive value="0" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="minexecutions" minOccurs="0" default="0">
                <simpleType>
                    <restriction base="int">
                        <minInclusive value="0" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </element>
            <element name="numThreads" type="int" />
            <element name="procedures" type="spm:procedure" minOccurs="1"
                maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
```

i want to generate this type of .xsd file using java code..? How can i do that.?

Specially how to generate Simple type elements and put restrictions on it ?

Comment: What is the source of the schema? Are you writing a GUI tool that is used to create Schemas? Or are only some parts of the above XML dynamic?

Comment: I do have Jaxb annotated java classes to generate schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating your own simple type to represent integers starting with `0`, you could leverage the existing `xs:nonNegativeInteger` type.  I'll demonstrate with an example.

**SpThread**

You can use the `@XmlSchemaType` annotation to specify what type should be generated in the XML schema for a field/property.

```
package forum11667335;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;

public class SpThread {

    private int durTime;

    @XmlSchemaType(name="nonNegativeInteger")
    public int getDurTime() {
        return durTime;
    }

    public void setDurTime(int durTime) {
        this.durTime = durTime;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

You can use the `generateSchema` method on `JAXBContext` to generate an XML schema:

```
package forum11667335;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(SpThread.class);

        jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

            @Override
            public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                result.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
                return result;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the XML schema that was generated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="spThread">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="durTime" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any XML-handling API to achieve this. JDOM is one of them. If you'd like an API specific to building XML Schemas which you then serialize into XML, you might want to check out [Eclipse MDT](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=xsd#xsd) API.

Comment: Hi Marko i am doing reading and writing of xml using jaxb , so is there any aanotaton or any other way to generate above type of schema ?

Comment: The [schemagen](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxb/schemagen.html) tool seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java2Schema  tool for generating schema from java classes, and also you can try JaxB 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you JAXB to any XML jobs you do. But normally XSD files are generated manually and then XML files are generated programatically using the XSD files. What are you trying to develop?