# java serialization with xml definition

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb

I am trying to find a good serialization library in java world. What I need:
1. It can serialize/deserialize object into xml, of course.
2. It has to use xml definition and code can be generated by any clients. I don't want to share code with my clients. I would rather share xml definition and let them generate code from it.

I found JAXB can do No1, but I am not sure if it can adopt No2. Is there anything else I can use.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JAXB for both the requirement, it can serialize/deserialize ( or we can say Unmarshal and Marshal). The JAXB classes generated from an XML Schema are POJOs with the standard JAXB annotations. As part of [Metro](https://jaxb.java.net/) there is a project for JAXB providing reference implementation. [JSR 222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) is developed by JCP for JAXB. You can have a look at these for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understand your second requirement, but xstream might be the answer

http://x-stream.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

> It has to use xml definition and code can be generated by any clients.

You can generate an XML schema from a JAXB model.  This XML schema can be considered the XML definition:

- [How to generate xsd file using java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667335/how-to-generate-xsd-file-using-java-code/11670962#11670962)

And a JAXB model can be generated from an XML schema.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html